# How to unit testing by mock methods in for a Vue component using ViTest?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tdd, vue-test-utils, vitest

Unit test vue component by mocking methods using vitest.

*MyComponent.vue*

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const isSelectAll = ref(true);
const selectAllModel = ref(false);

const onChange = () => {
    isSelectAll.value = true;
    selectAllModel.value = false;
};
const onVisibleChange = () => {
  // do something than call
  onChange();
};
</script>
```

I want to unit test method `onVisibleChange` by mocking `onChange` and check that `onChange` has been called.

*MyComponent.spec.js*

```
import { mount } from 'vitest';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent);
  const spy = vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'onChange');
  wrapper.vm.onVisibleChange();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(wrapper.vm.onChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
  // Both the expect gives error: AssertionError: expected "onChange" to be called at least once

  //Also tried
  const mock = vi.fn();
  wrapper.vm.onChange = mock;
  wrapper.vm.onVisibleChange();
  expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();   // AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called at least once
  expect(wrapper.vm.onChange).toHaveBeenCalled();  // TypeError: [Function onChange] is not a spy or a call to a spy!
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to test methods. Because the names of functions can be changed.

Better to test:

1. Emits from component. Maybe your `onChange()` includes emit. This emit should be tested.
2. Changes in templates. For example, your `onChange()` changes the template. So these changes should be tested too.
3. Calls other functions. For example, you have common functions which you use in all your project. This functions can be `spy.on`